# Group By and count values in columns based on value matching in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am new in Excel VBA and I have below table :

```
Column1 Column2
ABC XXX
ABC XXX
ABC XXX
ABC YYY
PQR XXX
PQR YYY
PQR YYY
XYZ XXX
XYZ XXX
XYZ YYY
XYZ YYY
XYZ YYY
XYZ XXX
XYZ XXX
```

I want the output like :

```
Column1 XXX    YYY
ABC      3  
ABC            1
PQR      1  
PQR            2
XYZ      4  
XYZ            3
```

Can anyone please suggest and VBA code or Excel function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use VBA for this, just use a pivot table.

By default you'll not get `column 1` values duplicated (first pivot table in screenshot).

If you need them duplicated, then you need to add a helper column in your data to make `column 1` values different depending on `column 2` value, e.g.:
`=A2&IF(B2="XXX",""," ")`

[image]